# Getting "Failed to Fetch" in result view of Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

We have Logic Apps running into Azure.  We are adding firewalls to some of our resources, and as such, I am migrating our Logic Apps to run inside an Integration Service Environment (ISE).  I am finding that when I go into the results of a run for the ISE version, if I drill into any activity (simple, complex, success or failure, doesn't matter), it spins for about 30 seconds, then shows:

Unexpected error. Failed to fetch[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'm having the same issue.  If you're using an internal/private ISE, you'll need to peer your VNET or access the history from a machine on the VNET.
This is explained in the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connect-virtual-network-vnet-isolated-environment-overview#ise-endpoint-access

> Also, make sure that you have network connectivity between the private
> endpoints and the computer from where you want to access the run
> history. Otherwise, when you try to view your logic app's run history,
> you get an error that says "Unexpected error. Failed to fetch".

Comment: Submitted an edit to add a reference to and quote from the official product documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connect-virtual-network-vnet-isolated-environment-overview#ise-endpoint-access

Comment: I accessed the Azure Portal through a VM on the same VNet for a test run as the ISE is set to 'internal' and the app ran fine and data was returned in the output dialogue. I guess I would need to set up a P2S connection between my desktop machine and the Azure VNet to have a robust debug experience from my desktop machine.

Answer (score 1):

make sure your ise access point is external while deploying the ise it self.
check it`s current access point from properties. if internal make sure to use a machine that is connected to the vnet. use pos/peering to do that.

Comment: What is meant by pos? I found it is not enough information to search Google.

Answer (score 0):

I my case to solve this issue, i press "ctrl + R" then "ctrl + F5", then i should wait a few minutes before opening les boxes and it's ok

If this error persists, you can download, full history in a csv file that you can analize, yes you need to rean JSON code and Sharepoint http requests

in your flow error message copy le run ID to seek it in your csv file in url

https://make.powerautomate.com/environments/Default-d035406542/solutions/b03b5e55-c8d9-ed11-a7c7-000d3a2726a5/flows/21fb6dc1-0412-3540684-f0a6881c120f/runs/08585210145218379217946437495CU195

with screenshot [here](http://fdi-sharepoint.e-monsite.com/blog/power-plateform/powerautomatehistoryunexpectederrorunabletofetch.html)